# ImportError: No module named 'selenium' error in my script

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the first time I have tried to use selenium. When I try to run my script on windows, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Rand/Desktop/test.py", line 15, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install Selenium. Open the command prompt and run the following command to install selenium:

pip install selenium